# Fast Networking Library is not importing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Why is the implementation of the FastNetworking Library not working in Android Studio?

I tried to resolve this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
```

But it is not working in Android Studio. I also added:

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

But this is not working either.

Please help me how to resolve this implementation because I want to use get and post APIs in my project. But this implementation not working in my Android Studio.

Build.gradle(Module app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jsonparsing"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Json Parsing"
include ':app'
```

Please can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi Shubham. Thank you for your question. Can you please include the exact text of the error message that you are receiving. Kind Regards.

Comment: Hi, I think the issue is related to Gradle version. As Elletlar mentioned, please share your logcat error message for better understanding

Comment: Why are you using Fast Networking Library? Use Retrofit instead of that. Retrofit is used widely and I strongly recommend it to you.

Comment: I think JitPack changed their dependency format at some point, so a lot of examples are out of date. Go to their site – https://jitpack.io – enter the repo like it shows there, and it'll generate the correct one for you; e.g., [under Step 2 here](https://jitpack.io/#amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking/v1.0.2).

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73306521/could-not-resolve-failed-to-resolve-com-amitshekhar-androidandroid-networki/73325806#73325806

Answer (score 0):

GOTO https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amitshekhar.android/android-networking/1.0.2

Download the AAR FILE

android studio GOTO file=>project structure=>dependencies=>app=> press + => select JAR/AAR, GIVE THE PATH to the file and let it install, this file worked for me and exactly how i did it ,GOOD LUCK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).