# Could not resolve / Failed to resolve - com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-library

i am trying to import network library , but android studio shows up with this meessage:ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2.

here is the build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfaild"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

when I import it into activity.java like below

Code:

```
import com.androidnetworking.AndroidNetworking;
import com.androidnetworking.common.Priority;
import com.androidnetworking.error.ANError;
import com.androidnetworking.interfaces.JSONArrayRequestListener;
```

there are some errors

```
1) Cannot resolve symbol 'androidnetworking'
2) Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidNetworking'
3) Cannot resolve symbol 'Priority'
4) Cannot resolve symbol 'JSONObjectRequestListener'
5) Cannot resolve symbol 'ANError'
```

Comment: Where is com.amitshekhar.android publish? It is on some public repo? Did you compiled and publish it locally? If not, it will not be found.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to check my answer below? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73325806/2271651

Answer (score 4):

The library is old and wasn't migrated to the Maven Central repository, since JCenter was deprecated.

You need to use it from [Jitpack repository](https://jitpack.io/#amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking/v1.0.2):

1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

2. Add the dependency to your app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.amitshekhariitbhu.Fast-Android-Networking:android-networking:v1.0.2'
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi, for the first step, where of the build.gradle file I should look? Is it the module build.gradle or project build.gradle? I didn't see allprojects {} anywhere

Comment: @JackStark for the first step, it's project build.gradle (aka root build.gradle)

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for it from one hour.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found the solution for the same you have write this in your *settings.gradle* file
`maven { url ("https://jcenter.bintray.com") }`

below the *mavenCentral()* line and make sure to add the above code to both the places as there you can see two *mavenCentral()* line in that file

and add the below line in your *gradle.properties*
`android.enableJetifier=true`

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in your gradle file (settings.gradle.kts) in both the places:

```
 maven { url = uri("https://jcenter.bintray.com") }
```

it should look like this :

```
 pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://jcenter.bintray.com") }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://jcenter.bintray.com") }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "json data parsing"
include(":app")
```